# Rest request for multipart/form-data using Java (cloning ruby client)

Tags: java, ruby, rest

it could be really dumb question but I'm struggling to find answer. I need to upload test screenshots to image comparison tool via post request, client for that was written on Ruby and I need to create my own Java client, currently stuck on 400 (bad request) Unfortunately I don't have logs from the server as it is not exposed, However the ruby client works fine.
Could you please tell me how the request body should look like? (that's my first experience with multipart)

Ruby code

```
  def submit_test(options = {})
  source_url =  options[:source_url] || ''
  fuzz_level =  options[:fuzz_level] || ''
  highlight_colour = options[:highlight_colour] || ''
  request = RestClient::Request.execute(
    method: :post,
    url: "#{@url_base}/tests",
    timeout: 120,
    multipart: true,
    payload: {
      test: {
        run_id: @run_id,
        name: options[:name],
        browser: options[:browser],
        size: options[:size],
        screenshot: options[:screenshot],
        source_url: source_url,
        fuzz_level: fuzz_level,
        highlight_colour: highlight_colour,
        crop_area: options[:crop_area]
      }
    }
  )
```

My Java code

```
@Test
public void spectre() throws MalformedURLException, JSONException, IOException {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\testfile.JPG"));
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputStream);
    final byte[] bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
    JSONObject test = new JSONObject();
    given()
            .multipart("run_id", 1)
            .multipart("name", "Landing Page")
            .multipart("browser", "firefox")
            .multipart("size", 1024)
            .multiPart("screenshot", "file1.png", bytes)
            .post("http://10.0.33.179:3333/tests");
    System.out.println(then().extract().statusCode());
   }
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a client to consume an API or are you only concerned with integration testing an existing API server?

Comment: Hi Paul, only integration, We are using spectre open source project:
https://github.com/wearefriday/spectre
issue is that client was written on ruby and this project is no longer maintained.
First post request is working fine (which is returning test run id)
But when I try to upload images it fails.

Comment: Anyone has any suggestions? I'm really stuck on this one